# How to pluck key value from object of array

Tags: javascript, arrayobject

i have object of array like this:

```
var arr = [{id: 1, url: 'something'},{id: 2, url: 'something2'}];
```

i want output like this :

```
[{id:1}, {id:2}]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use map function to pluck specific key value from object array.

```
var new_arr= arr.map(function (value, index, array) {

   return {"id": value.id}; 

});
```

Comment: You can remove the extra two parameters from the callback, they're not useful and just clutter the code.

Answer (score 6):

Just use [**Array#map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, url: 'something'},{id: 2, url: 'something2'}];
const mapped = arr.map(({id}) => ({ id }));

console.log(mapped);
```

In simple form

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, url: 'something'},{id: 2, url: 'something2'}];
const mapped = arr.map(item => { return { id: item.id };});

console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: Great answer, Suren. Can you point me to the what es6 syntaxes it leverages?

Comment: @NathanielRink If the first one does not work for you, instead of accepting {id} (object deconstruction), you can accept the object itself and use obj.id inside the arrow function

Comment: no, it works great actually. And I get the left side deconstrcution. But why does the right side only work if it's in parens? ()=> { id } is different from ()=>({id}) how?

Comment: @NathanielRink without the (), the {} are considered as the body of the arrow function

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the original array, just remove the attr `url`

```js
var arr = [{id: 1, url: 'something'},{id: 2, url: 'something2'}];
arr.forEach(o => delete o.url);
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca well, maybe that JSON was received from an API provider and the OP wants to clean up that object.

Comment: It still seems rather contrieved and un-idiomatic. I mean, is this honestly the first thing that popped into your head when you saw the question? Not trying to be dismissive, I sincerly want to know.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it's a valid approach because we don't have the complete context.  The OP only wants to remove that attr according to his/her question.